# why can't I use gnome in my Suse11 box

Tags: linux, suse

I newly installed a suse11 sp1 box. after the initial installation I do get a pretty gnome based desktop, but after reboot what i get is just a text prompt, the user I login with has
a run level of 5, so I'm puzzled, any of you can give me some tips on it?

In short, my question can be like this: how to enable gnome in Suse11.

Comment: if you run `startx` after logging in as an ordinary user, does the desktop come up?

Comment: @Paul no, startx gives me a very primitive x based desktop, I'm pretty sure it's gnome

Comment: Ok, once you login, can you do `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`